# Leave-one-out cross-validation with Liblinear

Tags: r, svm, cross-validation, liblinear

I've been using liblinear in R for an authorship attribution problem and have tried out LOO cross-validation just using the cross parameter in liblinear (so something like: `LiblineaR(data=mydata, labels=factor(mydata[,1]), cost=co, cross=nrow(mydata)`) and actually iterating over all of the rows so that I can see which texts have been misclassified or whatever:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
x = data[,2:ncol(data)]
y = factor(data[,1])

xTrain = x[-i,]
xTest = x[i,]
yTrain = y[-i]
yTest = y[i]

m=LiblineaR(data=xTrain, labels=yTrain, cost=co)
p=predict(m, xTest)}
```

It seems like I should get the same results from both methods, but for some of my datasets the first version is giving me way better results than the second--for example, 96% accuracy vs 50% accuracy (all works classified as being by the same author).
Has anyone dealt with this sort of thing?

Comment: If you can, give us data.

Comment: It's pretty large (well, only 28 texts, but >5500 features), but here it is. The features are just the frequency with which each word occurs in each text: [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24408497/english_dt.txt)